# Getting an error.. Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?) in Laravel 5

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, xampp

Getting error in laravel 5:

```
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you
enable the php_fileinfo extension?)
```

I have searched a lot on google but didn't get any appropriate answer which able to solve my problem.
 I got answer from stack flow but my apache don't have `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`file in `apache/ini.php`
and I am using xampp.

This is answer which I got from stack flow.
 Enabling mean just uncomment the line in your php.ini file

```
 i.e., From this ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll to extension=php_fileinfo.dll
but as I mentioned my apache don't have this extension.
```

please guide me

Comment: Does the term "fileinfo" appear in your `php.ini`?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: yes its appear like "fileinfo" in my XAMPP server